# Runtime error - C Programming

Tags: c, runtime, runtime-error

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    int cases, num1, num2, var, *ptr2, count, i;
    scanf("%d", &cases);
    ptr2 = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * cases);
    memset(ptr2, 0, sizeof(int) * cases);
    if (ptr2) {
        for (count = 0; count < cases; count++) {
            scanf("%d", &num1);
            scanf("%d", &num2);
            for (i = 0; i < num1; i++) {
                scanf("%d", &var);
                ptr2[count] += var / num2;
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < cases; i++) {
            printf("%d\n", ptr2[i]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the description of the problem https://a2oj.com/p?ID=17
It runs on VS IDE very well, but for some reason when I submit it their environment gives me an runtime error.

Comment: "gives me an runtime error." --> what is the text of that run time error?  What input was used?

Comment: i cannot know, it just says runtime error

Comment: Curious, why the `if (ptr2){` test _after_ using `ptr2` in `memset(ptr2,0...);`

Comment: You don't know what input was used?

Comment: Yeah i don't know,they do have their test cases 
& true maybe i have to put that line after the if statement

Comment: If test case input contains non-numeric input or unexpected numeric input like -1, 2000000000 for `cases`, certainly bad this will happen.  Suggest qualifying input by checking the return value of `scanf()` and if OK, test for a reasonable range of input value.

Comment: Thanks chux, it's solved after switching 'if (ptr2){' with 'memset(ptr2,0...);'

Comment: Even though switching the line `memset()` location _apparently_ solved something, certainly code needs more error checking.

Comment: I didn't have to check since the problem says that the input would be from 1 - 100.

Comment: " input would be from 1 - 100. " is not in the post.  Why omit critical information?

Comment: "I didn't have to check " does not mean code must not do error checking.   Adding error checking, even when not required, not only helps perform checks, it also helps in debugging and can save time - likely negating the need for this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's solved after switching 'if (ptr2){' with 'memset(ptr2,0...);' – Andrew Naguib